# Как получить высоту элемента в React js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
import Header from './Components/Header';

function App() {
return (

<div className="headerContainer">
  <Header/>
</div>
);
};
```

export default App;

Как я могу получить высоту ***div***а с классом ***headerContainer***

Answer (score 2):

С помощью ref [документация](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

```
export default function App() {
  const refComponent = createRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const height = refComponent.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;

    console.log(height, "height");
  }, [refComponent]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 ref={refComponent}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-moser-5u02n?file=/src/App.js:70-397)